# Weird Error "No known class method for selector 'sceneWithSize:'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, sprite-kit

I've recently started working with Sprite Kit now i've just opened a new sprite kit project and removed the `MyScene` class as I don't need it. I've then created my own subclass of SKView called `PhyscisScene` now when i've done this and replaced the code in `ViewController.m`I get this error on **line 24** in `ViewController.m`: `No known class method for selector 'sceneWithSize:'` Below is all my Class files i've changed hopefully you can tell me whats going on:

## ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PhysicsScene.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [PhysicsScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

@end
```

## PhysicsScene.m

```
#import "PhysicsScene.h"

@implementation PhysicsScene

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Does the PhysicsScene interface (probably in PhysicsScene.h) contain a method like +(id)sceneWithSize:(CGSize)size; ? Sounds like it doesn't.

Comment: @danh No, but another project i've create for sprite kit doesn't contain it as well but compiles without any compile errors also sceneWithSize shouldn't have to manually entered should it as it was already there when the project was created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PhysicsScene` is a subclass of `SKView`. It looks like `PhysicsScene` should be a subclass of `SKScene`.  The solution is to convert `PhysicsScene` to a subclass of [`SKScene`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKScene/sceneWithSize%3a) since that is what it looks like you want to use it for.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs, sceneWithSize is a class method of SKScene, not SKView.